# Integral of a function with different value for different intervals

Tags: integration, limits, definite-integrals

I have a function
$$
f(x) =
\begin{cases}
x & \text{if } 0 \leq x \leq \pi \\
0 & \text{if } \pi < x \leq 2\pi
\end{cases}
$$

I have to solve
$$
\int_0^\pi f(x) \sin(nx) \, \mathrm{d}x
$$

How do I do that? Since $f(x) = x$ for $0 \leq x \leq \pi$ and my integral limits are $a=0$ and $b=\pi$, can I just substitute $f(x) = x$ into the integral or do I have to look at the integral for both intervals?

Does it makes sense to look at the limits from $a=0$ to $b=\pi$ if the function, for instance, is only defined outside these limits?

Comment: Question a bit unclear. Your integral is ready. Integrate it . Why wait?

Comment: Yes you can ignore where $x>\pi$ and just assume $f(x)=x$ everywhere.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can substitute f(x) = x into the integral.

You cannot integrate the function under the limits if it is not defined there.

Answer (score 2):

You are allowed to write
$$
\int_0^\pi f(x) \sin(nx) \, \mathrm{d}x=\int_0^\pi x \sin(nx) \, \mathrm{d}x
$$ then integrate by parts to get

> $$
> \int_0^\pi f(x) \sin(nx) \, \mathrm{d}x= \frac{\pi(-1)}n^{n-1}.
> $$

Answer (score 1):

Since we are only to integrate $x \mapsto f(x)\sin nx$ over $[0,\pi]$ on which $f$ is by definition the identity map, we can compute the integral $\int_{0}^{\pi} f(x)\sin (nx) dx$ by
$$
\int f(x)\sin (nx) dx = \int x\sin (nx)dx = \frac{-1}{n}\int xd\cos (nx) \simeq \frac{-1}{n}x\cos nx + \frac{1}{n^{2}}\sin (nx)
$$
where $\simeq$ denotes the equality sign up to a constant.